# Why does Windows Media Player keep starting songs part-way through?

Tags: windows-7, windows-media-player

I'm running Windows 7, WMP12.

I've noticed loads of times I select to play an album, and it jumps into the 1st track part-way through. I'd always assumed it was remembering where I'd got to last time, but today I downloaded a brand new album and went to play it for the very first time... same thing. It's not an album or even an artist I've ever owned before.

update: might be this https://web.archive.org/web/20090719234229/http://www.windows7taskforce.com/view/2936

Comment: How are you starting the song? Double-clicking in WMP? From the keyboard?

Comment: Normally right-click the album and select play, as I recall.

Comment: Very strange. I can't reproduce it. Not sure what would cause that.

Comment: Do you have any plug-ins loaded into WMP? If so, please check if you still get the issue with all plug-ins disabled/uninstalled.